# Carry out action when multiple properties change

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

I have three different properties, x, y, z. If they all turn nil, I need to take an action, and if one of them is set to a value != nil, I have to carry out a different action.

My current implementation is the following:

```
@property (readonly) NSNumber *meta;

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingMeta
{
  return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"x", @"y", @"z", nil];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"meta" options:0 context:NULL];
}

- (NSNumber *)meta
{
  BOOL meta = x || y || z;
  return [NSNumber numberWithBool:meta];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  BOOL meta = [[self meta] boolValue];
  if (meta != _flags.meta) {
    if (meta) {
      [self showSomeStuff];
    }
    else {
      [self hideSomeStuff];
    }

  _flags.meta = meta;
  }
}
```

It works, but I hope there is a much easier and better solution for something like this, that I am currently overlooking. Hit me!

Comment: This is actually a very clever solution. :)

Comment: Well thanks, but observing self seems just plain wrong to me.

Comment: really? I do it all the time, specifically so I can keep my `@synthesize`'d properties, but still respond to when things change.  Just don't forget to remove yourself as an observer in `-dealloc`.

Comment: Well I guess my judgement was off then, and I will happily continue with this; Of course I won't forget to remove the observer - think of all the messages that my deallocated instance could send to itself (deallocated) if some property (on itself, deallocated) changes. (Okay, okay, it's the right thing to do, also the lovely exception would be thrown, but I think you don't even leak anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think how you have it is about the cleanest and most Cocoa-like way you could.  And for the record, observing `self` is not a bad design decision.